# How can I access a method of the consumer class inside a method created at runtime in a method of the parameterized role using Moose with Perl?

Tags: perl, roles, moose

I define a method inside a parametrized role that needs to create a new class at run time 
using `Moose::Meta::Class->create`  and apply that exact parametrized role to it. I am also making a new method for that role using

```
$new_class->meta->add_method( some_name => sub {
 my ($self) = @_;
 ...
})
```

inside the sub {...} I want to access a method of the consumer class and use it for something, I have tried using `$self->get_method`, it didn't work, how do I do this?

Please notice that the `$self` inside the sub above is `MooseX::Role::Parameterized::Meta::Role::Parameterizable`

I also have another question, if I do this:

```
my $object = Moose::Meta::Class->create(
       "some_type",

);
```

Why isn't `$object` of type some_type and it's some ugly  `MooseX::Role::Parameterized::Meta::Role::Parameterizable` and how do I get to the object of type some_type?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, the reason is because Perl's OO doesn't allow you to add a method to just one instance of a class, so Moose has to fake it by creating a subclass with the extra method and reblessing the unique object into that subclass.

Note that, if you are doing things correctly and doing your introspection with `isa`, `has`, and/or `does` rather than by trying to rely on the name of the object's blessed package, this doesn't matter.  The object still `isa` some_type, `has` all of some_type's attributes, and `does` all of some_type's roles even though it's now blessed into a package with an ugly auto-generated name.

Comment: re: ` Moose has to fake it by creating a subclass with the extra method and reblessing the unique object into that subclass`.  I think this maybe happens in all Class based OO languages (I know that Ruby also does it this way).  Now Prototyped based OO would be different.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your underlying problem is nearly exactly what I described at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758884/how-can-i-access-the-meta-class-of-the-module-my-moose-role-is-being-applied-to): from within the role definition, you need to get at the class (and its meta-class) of the object or class the role is being applied to.  This isn't possible from within normal roles, but it's possible through parameterized roles.

Comment: Ether I have read your post several times before posting mine, I have tried multiple combinations creating a metaclass as you did and then applying the role to it, and then trying to add a method ->meta->add_method and then trying to instantiate it, the instantiating part didn't went very well, that's why I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here. Let's assume you have

```
my $new_class = Moose::Meta::Class->create('FooBar');
```

then `$new_class` *is* the meta object for `FooBar`. So, if you want to add a method to `FooBar` you would say

```
$new_class->add_method(foo => sub { … });
```

which would basically be the same as

```
FooBar->meta->add_method(foo => sub { … });
```

You should also probably use `find_meta()` from [Moose::Util](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Util.pm). This will return the correct meta object (if there is one) even if your class doesn't have a `meta` method or it uses it for something else.

As said, I'm not sure this answers your question.