# Role that modifies or provides a method

Tags: perl, moose

What if I want a role to *modify* a method if the consuming class does not have it, or *provide* a default method where the consuming class does not?

In one case, using a method modifier works.  In the other case, just defining an ordinary method works.  Is there a method that works in both cases?

Concrete example:

```
package UsualFavorites;
use Moose::Role;

around favorite_things {
    my ($self, $orig) = @_;
    $self->$orig(), qw/doorbells sleighbells/;
}
```

If the consuming class does not define a `favorite_things` method, I want it to end up with a `favorite_things` method that just returns `(doorbells, sleighbells)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define the method in the role. If the class has a method with the same name then the method from the role will be ignored.

```
package UsualFavorites;
use Moose::Role;

sub favorite_things {
    return ();
}
around favorite_things => sub {
    my ($orig, $self) = @_;
    return ($self->$orig(), qw/doorbells sleighbells/);
};

package Consumer;
use Moose;
with 'UsualFavorites';

sub favorite_things {
    return qw/shipbells/;
}
```

Comment: Wow, *much* simpler than my hack. Re. "If the class has a method with the same name then the method from the role will be ignored." Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I don’t know. But see http://metacpan.org/source/ETHER/Moose-2.1404/lib/Moose/Meta/Role/Application/ToClass.pm#L133

Answer (score 3):

You *could* do this using [`MooseX::Role::Parameterized`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Role::Parameterized):

Favorites.pm

```
package Favorites;

use MooseX::Role::Parameterized;

parameter method_name => (
    isa     => 'Str',
    default => 'favorite_things'
);

role {
    my $p = shift;
    my %args = @_;
    my $consumer = $args{consumer};

    my $method_name = $p->method_name;
    my @default_values = qw/doorbells sleighbells/;

    if ( $consumer->find_method_by_name($method_name) ) {
        around $method_name => sub {
            my $orig = shift;
            my $self = shift;

            $self->$orig(@_), @default_values;
        };
    }
    else {
        method $method_name => sub {
            my $self = shift;

            return @default_values;
        };
    }
};

no Moose::Role;

1;
```

Santa.pm (Santa likes doorbells, right?):

```
package Santa;

use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

with 'Favorites';

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

1;
```

ACDC.pm

```
package ACDC;

use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

with 'Favorites';

sub favorite_things {
    my $self = shift;

    return 'Hells Bells';
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

1;
```

favorites_test

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use ACDC;
use Santa;

my $kris_kringle = Santa->new;
say 'Santa likes ', join(', ', $kris_kringle->favorite_things);

my $acdc = ACDC->new;
say 'AC/DC likes ', join(', ', $acdc->favorite_things);
```

#### Output:

```
Santa likes doorbells, sleighbells
AC/DC likes Hells Bells, doorbells, sleighbells
```

---

Note that you have to do additional gymnastics if your role is consumed by another parameterized role, or if your role is applied to an object instance. [Ether](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40468/ether) describes both of these cases in [How can I access the meta class of the module my Moose role is being applied to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759168/176646) and notes in a comment that:

> I no longer consider the above a "best practice", and indeed have refactored out all of this (ab)use of MXRP. IMHO if you need to access `$meta` from within a role, you have something stinky in your design.

Is there any reason you can't simply make `favorite_things` required?

Answer (score 1):

Taking ThisSuitIsBlackNot's solution and simplifying a bit, I have:

```
package UsualFavorites;
use Moose::Role;
use strict;
use warnings;

around favorite_things => sub {
    my ($orig, $self) = @_;
    $self->$orig(), qw/doorbells sleighbells/;
};

sub favorite_things { () }

package Santa;

use Moose;
use strict;
use warnings;
with 'UsualFavorites';

package ACDC;

use Moose;
use strict;
use warnings;
with 'UsualFavorites';

sub favorite_things {
    my $self = shift;
    return 'Hells Bells';
}

package main;

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $kris_kringle = Santa->new;
say 'Santa likes ', join(', ', $kris_kringle->favorite_things);

my $acdc = ACDC->new;
say 'AC/DC likes ', join(', ', $acdc->favorite_things);
```

So I both have the around *and* I have the default implementation in the role, and it seems to work.

Comment: Nice, much cleaner than my approach. This is also what [Denis Ibaev suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29856616/176646). As far as the "seems to work," Denis said that "If the class has a method with the same name then the method from the role will be ignored" but I can't find this in the documentation anywhere. Do you know if this behavior is documented?

Comment: This is just simple, regular old inheritance.  Since the Role is a parent class, the child class is just overriding it.  And could call `$self->SUPER::favorite_things` as well, though there's no need here.

Comment: I don't think that's right...roles are not parent classes. You can see the inheritance relationships by calling `say for __PACKAGE__->meta->linearized_isa;` inside the consuming class; the name of the role is not returned. The reason `$self->SUPER::favorite_things` works is because it resolves to the method in the current package (which happens to be named `favorite_things`), not the method in the role. Create a `foo` method in the role and call `$self->SUPER::foo` in the consuming class; you will get `Can't locate object method "foo" via package "Consumer"`

Comment: Denis Ibaev [pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852476/role-that-modifies-or-provides-a-method#comment47842552_29856616) how methods from roles are applied to classes; indeed, methods are skipped if they are already defined in the consuming class: `next if $class_method && $class_method->body != $method->body;`